# Django 1.3 or Django 1.2 for a new project

Tags: django

I need to start a new project with Django, but I'm not sure what version of Django, according your experience, what you'll recomend?

Comment: what would make you think you wouldn't want the latest? Are there restrictions on your project? 1.3 is the latest and therefore probably the one you should go for

Comment: just one limitation: the plugins compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take note of your development / production server Python versions.

Django 1.2 is tested on Python 2.3 and higher while Django 1.3 drops Python 2.3 support, meaning you will have to use 2.4 above.

Granted, most servers these days have a minimum version of at least Python 2.4 so it shouldn't be a problem - it's good to take note.

You may wish to refer to Django 1.2 and 1.3's release notes. They document the list of changes between each versions and list out compatibility issues between each release (for example, you may wish to upgrade from 1.2 to 1.3 in the future and want to see the changes).

- [Django 1.2 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/)
- [Django 1.3 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/)

If you have no restrictions, I strongly recommend Django 1.3. It has Generic Class Views and a couple of new nifty stuff.

Answer (score 4):

1.3 of course.

From their webiste...

> Which version is better?
>   We improve Django almost every day and are pretty good about keeping the code stable. Thus, using the latest development code is a safe and easy way to get access to new features as they're added. If you choose to follow the development version, keep in mind that there will occasionally be backwards-incompatible changes. You'll want to pay close attention to the development timeline. If you're just looking for a stable deployment target and don't mind waiting for the next release, you'll want to stick with the latest official release (which will always include detailed notes on any changes you'll need to make while upgrading).